# Convert Set<String> to Set<InetAddress> in Java in a cleaner way

Tags: java, java-stream, string-conversion, inetaddress

I have the following code:

```
Set<String> ips = allowedIpsToDescriptions.keySet();
```

where `allowedIpsToDescriptions` is a `Map<String, String>`

I'm trying to convert `Set<String>` to `Set<InetAddress>` and here's my code:

```
Set<InetAddress> allowedIpsInetAddr = new HashSet<>();
    
    for (String ip : ips) {
      InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
      allowedIpsInetAddr.add(inetAddress);
    }
```

Is there a cleaner / more efficient way of doing this using streams perhaps?

Comment: This code is perfectly fine. Using streams would be slower, not "more efficient".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is good way to implement but you should handle `null` as expected input to prevent localhost as it is the default value returned by `getHostName`. Then ensure that input is pure url without port to prevent `UnknownHostException`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you could use `map` to call `InetAddress.getByName` on each string:

```java
// Doesn't compile.
Set<InetAddress> allowedIpsInetAddr = ips.stream()
    .map(InetAddress::getByName)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Unfortunately this fails to compile:

```
error: incompatible thrown types UnknownHostException in functional expression
    .map(InetAddress::getByName)
         ^
```

`map` callbacks can't throw checked exceptions like `UnknownHostException`. You can work around this by converting them into [`UncheckedIOException`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html):

```java
Set<InetAddress> allowedIpsInetAddr = ips.stream()
    .map(ip -> {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: How is this "cleaner / more efficient" than the original code?

Comment: It isn't necessarily better. People who like functional idioms might prefer a streaming version. Then again, they might find the exception handling too ugly to bear.

Comment: Someone who strongly prefers streaming could hide the exception handling inside a helper function so it's not such an eyesore.